# Why is the Low Fare Searcg Fare API suddenly throwing 500 Error

Tags: amadeus

I was working with the API in sandbox and everything was going on fine and then suddenly I started getting the error below. Did I do something wrong? This has been like this for some hours now.

Request URL
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=NYC&destination=MAD&departureDate=2019-08-01&max=2

```
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "code": 141,
      "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Error 500 indicates server side error, not client error. You should contact the provider. "System error" message describes this quite well.

Comment: Are you still facing this problem ? Would you mind to share your header you can blur sensitive data/information

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue for this API in the test environment  approx from 7am GMT to 8am GMT. Everything is back to normal now